# I can't change the default zoom when use kml files on google maps API

Tags: api, maps, zooming, kml

I'm showing a kml layer using the Google Maps API, it automatically zoom to the extent of the kml objects, but I need to zoom closer and I can't find the way. The ZOOM parameter doesn't work. Already tried with { preserveViewport: true }

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script><script>
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    preserveViewport: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://consorciohidraulico.com.ar/userfiles/kml/julieta.kml'
  });
  ctaLayer.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div id="map-canvas" style="height:300px;">
            Mapa Google Kml</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The new code, according to user geocodezip, is:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script><script>
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://consorciohidraulico.com.ar/userfiles/kml/julieta.kml',
    preserveViewport: true
});
  ctaLayer.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div id="map-canvas" style="height:300px;">
            Mapa Google Kml</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That generates a gray image without a map. Something is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

The `preserveViewport: true` option doesn't belong in the [mapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions), it belongs in the [KmlLayerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerOptions).

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'http://consorciohidraulico.com.ar/userfiles/kml/julieta.kml',
      preserveViewport: true
    });
```

And if you are using {preserveViewport: true} you do need to set the initial center of the map.  There are two **required** [mapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#MapOptions), center and zoom.  They can be set automatically by the KmlLayer when preserveViewport is false, but if it is true, you *have* to set them.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B3nnh/2/)

If you want to have the KmlLayer initialize the map, setting the center and zoom level to fit the KML, then change the zoom, you need to keep `preserveViewport` at its default value of false, listen for the first `zoom_changed` event (the KmlLayer initializing it), then set it to your desired value.

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://consorciohidraulico.com.ar/userfiles/kml/julieta.kml',
    preserveViewport:false
});
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    // set the zoom level to 14.
    map.setZoom(14);
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B3nnh/3/)

Comment: I just tried that and now the map is not displayed, the whole picture where the map should be is displayed in gray.

Comment: The same code works for you? Is there any site where I can test it? In my site does not work.

Comment: Perfect, I tried again in my site and now works. But I have another problem now: how can I center the map automatically in the kml? I just want to change the zoom.